# Power Apps unexpected character

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, syntax-error, character, powerapps

Why doesn't my Power App accept this:

[image: Error screenshot]

He always want `;` instead `,` why?

[image]

And if I try that, I have an unexpected character:

```
SubmitForm(Form1); ResetForm(Form1)
```

Thank you guys
I tried everything.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SubmitForm(Form1);; ResetForm(Form1)
```

This change is required because of your application language.

---

Some separators and operators in Power apps formula will change based on application author's language:

[image]

You have to use `;` as separator between parameters of a function and `;;` as separator between two functions.

**Microsoft official documentation**: [Power Apps - Formula separators and chaining operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/global#formula-separators-and-chaining-operator)